# How can I import table records in HeidiSql?

Tags: mysql, heidisql

Im using HeidiSQL and I have imported database from another one.
All table structures are imported but not records.
I want to import all records for all tables.
I have tried to import records for one table using import csv option but its inserting only one record and through error.

Comment: *and through error* And what is error message?

Comment: Error: Your file was imported but the server returned 64 warning and/or notes

Comment: Now you must look at "64 warning and/or notes" which were returned by server.

Comment: If you have .CSV file which you want to import - use `LOAD DATA INFILE` executed in Heidi instead of importing vie Heidi.

Comment: Please edit your question and put in the error message - the more information that is in the question itself the better, rather than having it scattered through the comments! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Is what you're trying to import in CSV format, or is it SQL statements?